# About making wiki pages and ROS packages

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I designed a wiki page for the ROS wiki, how can I send it for revision or upload it?

Thanks beforehand!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206408/about-making-wiki-pages-and-ros-packages/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can edit and create wiki pages yourself. Just create an account and go ahead.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-04-01**:
About the design, how can I add the information about the creator, maintainer, status of the package, ...?
I have this till now: [turtlebot_2dnav](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_2dnav)

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-04-01**:
If you click on "Documentation Status" on your wiki page you will see that your new repository has not yet been indexed. You have just added the repo to the rosdistro half an hour ago. The job will get generated over night and then it might take up to three days to index your repo.